# Visual flow not able to select resource on Record create

Tags: visualforce, force.com, visual-workflow, flow

I have build a visual flow that creates accounts records.
For some reason when I am mapping the fields, the system doesn't allow me to select resource, to some of the fields, please see image below:

[image: No Option]

When it should display the other options like

1. variables
2. Screen Input Fields
3. Screen choice fields
4. Choices

But to some other fields I am able to select the resource:
[image]

I am wondering if there is something that I am missing on those specific fields setup that is blocking the system to select this option or if it is a salesforce bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that the input field on the main screen was type text, where the field that I wanted to map was type currency.
Visual flow was clever enough to filter the fields, and not display any option as I wanted to map a currency field.